# angular - access the element from ng-disabled

Tags: html, angularjs, htmlelements

I want to pass `this` (the element) - a `button` to my `controller` by `ng-disable`.
here is my `HTML`:

```
<button type ="button" class = "btn btn-default" ng-click= "open()" ng-disabled = "checkRowId(this)">
</button>
```

And my `controller` :

```
$scope.checkRowId = function(btn){
   console.log(btn); //undefined
}
```

The log shoes `undefined`, is there a way to pass a `element` like a `button` via `ng-disabled`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to pass element via ng-disabled. You can create one directive say "disabled-ele" and put your element disabling logic there.

Example Code:

```
.directive('disabledEle', function() {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'EA',
                        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                            if(attrs.disabledEle.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
                                element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            } else {
                                element.removeAttr('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

<button type ="button" value="Click" class = "btn btn-default" disabled-ele="false">Click
                    </button>
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.