# How can I access the responding element where ng-disabled is attached to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a clean way to access the element where the ng-disabled property is attached to inside the function that is given to it?

**Html element:**

```
 <input class="needsDisabling" ng-disabled="isFieldDisabled()" type="text">
```

**isFieldDisabled function in controller:**

How can I access the element where the ng-disabled prop is attached to in this function ?

```
$scope.isFieldDisabled = function () {
        // How can I access the element where the ng-disabled prop is attached to in this function ? 

        // if (element has class "needsDisabling")
        // return true;
}
```

> I am looking for another way then passing the element as a parameter
>   in the function.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezr0z7zc/)

Comment: What exactly do you need to access regarding the element? Why don't you pass an argument to the isFieldDisabled method?

Comment: You might want to look at this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429563/angular-access-the-element-from-ng-disabled

Comment: Also, you could use the related ng-model of the input element (it's missing in this case, so I guess you would like to add it)

Comment: There is a reason why I want to access it like this. But I guess there is no other way then passing it as a parameter to the function :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) was designed to work with your model (**#2**) and does not allow to manipulate your DOM elements manually in your controllers (which is considered a bad practice in angularjs). But anyway you can still create your [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and manipulate `disabled` property manually (**#1**):

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('myDisabled', [function () {
        var myDisabled = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.myDisabled).apply(scope, element);
                }, function(val) {
                    element.prop('disabled', val);
                });
            }
        }
        return myDisabled;
}])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.isFieldDisabled = function (element) {
      return angular.element(element).hasClass('disabled');
    }
    
    $scope.inputs = [{}, { disabled: true }, {}];
    
    $scope.isInputDisabled = function (input){
      return !!input.disabled;
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.js" ></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h2>#1</h2>
    <input class="needsDisabling disabled" my-disabled="isFieldDisabled" type="text"/>
    <input class="needsDisabling" my-disabled="isFieldDisabled" type="text"/>
    <input class="needsDisabling disabled" my-disabled="isFieldDisabled" type="text"/>
    <h2>#2</h2>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-repeat="input in inputs" ng-disabled="isInputDisabled(input)" ng-model="input.value"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the element to the controller's function in angularjs, but why not take advantage of the `ng-class` directive as your class and disabled values depend on each other?

```
ng-class="{needsDisabling: isDisabled}" ng-disabled="isDisabled"
```

I cannot think of a reason why you should not do it like this because;

- If the class is not dynamic then there is no need for `ng-disabled`.
  You could just use `disabled="disabled"` but I guess that is not the reason.
- If the value of class IS dynamically switched outside of angular's
  knowledge, then that part of the solution is problematic and should
  be changed.

Another reason to deal with this issue in angularjs itself is to create your own directive as someone here pointed out.